# Wrap arround an higher element

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I've a list with some elements in there.
If any item has the same high, all items wrapping correctly.
But if an single item has a bigger high than the others, the items wrapping at the bottom of the higher element.

Here you can see my example: https://jsfiddle.net/qqouoL6n/

Here is my simple html list:

```
<div id="flexbox-container">
  <div class="small-container"></div>
  <div class="big-container"></div>
  <div class="small-container"></div>
  <div class="small-container"></div>
  <div class="small-container"></div>
  <div class="small-container"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, there is one div, with an class that represents an higher items then the other ones.
Here is the css:

```
#flexbox-container {
  width: 220px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 10px;
}

.big-container {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.small-container {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100px;
  height: 110px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

I am using flexbox to float these items. If all items has the same high, everything works as expected. But, if the second items has the double high as the other elements, the items ignore the gap.

I want to achieve, that the gap is filled up with the next item, how can I do this?

Comment: have a look at [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You could change it to use `flex-direction: column` instead, but you'll get the same issue if one of the items is wider than the others. You'd also need to specify a `height` attribute on the `#flexbox-container` DIV to ensure that the columns did indeed wrap rather than continue down the page.

Something like this:

```
#flexbox-container {
  width: 220px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Here's the [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4kr72uk/).